# How to run fdisk with puppet on AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, puppet, amazon-ami

I am trying to create an AMI using Packer and puppet-masterless builder. I want to mount a 20G ebs volume to `/test`.

Basically I want to automate the below commands using puppet. I tried but no success yet. I am new to puppet and tried using lvm module but am facing issues. Can someone suggest proper way to achieve below please?

```
fdisk /dev/xvdk
mkfs -t xfs /dev/xvdk1
mkdir -p /test
echo "/dev/xvdk1  /test xfs defaults  0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount /test
```

Comment: Note that there is generally no need to create a partition, you can create the filesystem directly on the block device and mount the block device directly.  This also makes resizing the filesystem much simpler in the future.  Is there a reason you're not doing this?

Comment: Noap. I just got these steps from Linux Expert. If you can give me steps I certainly try them.

Comment: Remove the `fdisk` line, and everywhere else, such as in Matt's answer below, just use the device `/dev/xvdk` instead of the partition `/dev/xvdk1`.  Partitioning is sometimes used on physical disks on physical servers but is generally unnecessary in the cloud and is one less thing to go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you are using the `lvm` module, here is how you would accomplish what you described in Puppet.

```
# there is no Puppet intrinsic for this
exec { '/sbin/fdisk /dev/xvdk': unless => '/bin/lsblk /dev/xvdk' }

# create the /dev/xvdk1 filesystem
filesystem { '/dev/xvdk1':
  ensure  => present,
  fs_type => xfs,
  require => Exec['/sbin/fdisk /dev/xvdk1'], # after partition created
}

# create directory
file { '/test': ensure => directory }

# mount /test
mount { '/test':
  ensure    => mounted, # mount /test
  device    => '/dev/xvdk1', # next five lines fstab mount options
  fstype    => xfs,
  options   => defaults,
  dump      => 0,
  pass      => 0,
  atboot    => true, # add entry to fstab
  require   => File['/test'], # after dir created
  subscribe => Filesystem['/dev/xvdk1'], # remount if/when filesystem changes
}
```

Note that you are not creating a volume group or logical volume in this process, and you may want to be (especially the logical volume) for this to succeed. However, the above Puppet resources will perfectly execute the commands you have described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mount /dev/xvdk1 /test
```

Hope it helps

Comment: please add highlighting and maybe explain a little bit more why you think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use the [`mount` type](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/mount.html) in Puppet.